# Make the eyes look less like an insect

Tags: modeling

I have created an object that should finaly look somewhat like this:

[image]

In Blender it now looks this way:

[image]

[image]

How can I make the eyes look better? I want to add eyelids. Maybe this would already help but I'm not sure about this. I'm still learning how to work with Blender.

Regards, Marek

Comment: This is more a tutorial question. I think you can squeeze more on the eyeballs to make them even flatter.

Comment: Go into edit mode then us W > *Shade Smooth*.

Comment: What does W stand for?

Answer (score 2):

Tp make the sharp edges disappear select your object and use smooth shading.
[image]
[image]

On top of that you can always add add a **Subdivision Surface** Modifier

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You stated.

> I want to add eyelids

So for many people this is close to asking for a tutorial.  I suggest you look on some video site for .. blender face tutorial.  This site so far does not supply tutorial videos and all questions like this are likely to put on hold.  That is just standard.
Most people here have seen tutorial videos on face creation.  Consider watching videos and practicing for a couple of hours.

Quick instructions.
Remove three horizontal adjacent faces.  Delete the faces. Shape to crude eyelid. Select the border. Extrude and Scale Smaller.  Try more complex techniques later.

[image]

Here is a similar topic.
[Trying to replicate a 2D Eye Rig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13834/trying-to-replicate-a-2d-eye-rig/13841#13841)

It may contain references to other videos.
Search this site for face .. or extrusion.

Comment: Thanks for your little tutorial. My intention was realy just to get help and ideas to make the eyes look better. The remark about the eyelids was just to point out where I want to go to. Compared to the 2D grafic the eyes are looking way to big. I guess its due to the round scape of the body that does not effect the flat 2D grafic. I guess it is a matter of the perspective. Since I'm a novice in sketching and painting I'm not able to translate the 2D image into a correct good looking 3D grafic object. Maybe I have to change the hole body to make the eyes look smaler?

Comment: P.S. I have made the 2D image with inkscape. The idea to make a 3D object out of it came later.

Comment: The yellow hold box above will help you to understand this site better.  You should mark any answer that helps you if possible.  There are two to choose from.  This site is intended to be more of a quick help desk.